# How can I find out the exact location where the recursive operation is working?

Tags: powershell, filesystems

My problem is, that the string for replacement needs to change according to the folder depth the designated file is located and I don't have a clue how to get that info. I need to work with relative addresses.

I want the script to be run from 2 folder levels above the folder where all the files are that need correcting. So I've set the $path in line 1. That folder suppose to be 'depth 0'. In here, the replacement string needs to be in it's native form -> `stylesheet.css`.

For files in the folders one level below 'depth 0' the string for replacement needs to be prefixed with `../` once -> `../stylesheet.css`.

For files in the folders two level below 'depth 0' the string for replacement needs to be prefixed with `../` twice ->  `../../stylesheet.css`.
...and so on...

I'm stuck here:

```
$depth = $file.getDepth($path) #> totally clueless here
```

I need `$depth` to contain the number of folders under the root `$path`.

**How can I get this?** Here's the rest of my code:

```
$thisLocation = Get-Location
$path = Join-Path -path $thisLocation -childpath "\Files\depth0"
$match = "findThisInFiles"
$fragment = "stylesheet.css" #> string to be prefixed n times
$prefix = "../" #> prefix n times according to folder depth starting at $path (depth 0 -> don't prefix)
$replace = "" #> this will replace $match in files
$depth = 0

$htmlFiles = Get-ChildItem $path -Filter index*.html -recurse

foreach ($file in $htmlFiles)
{
    $depth = $file.getDepth($path) #> totally clueless here
    $replace = ""
    for ($i=0; $i -lt $depth; $i++){
        $replace = $replace + $prefix
    }
    $replace = $replace + $fragment

    (Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
    Foreach-Object { $_ -replace $match, $replace } |
    Set-Content $file.PSPath
}
```

Comment: Ok, I'm going to remove my comments not because it's just distracting from your question

Comment: You may be able to use `-split` and `-replace` to split it to find out how many 'segments' so to speak there are. Split on a `Backslash` and replace empty spaces. It can be tricky to get to work though. I did it in the past before i learned about `Split-Path` which satisfies most needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function I've written that uses `Split-Path` recursively to determine the depth of a path:

```
Function Get-PathDepth ($Path) {
    $Depth = 0
    While ($Path) {
        Try {
            $Parent = $Path | Split-Path -Parent
        }
        Catch {}

        if ($Parent) {
            $Depth++
            $Path = $Parent
        }
        else {
            Break
        }
    }
    Return $Depth
}
```

Example usage:

```
$MyPath = 'C:\Some\Example\Path'

Get-PathDepth -Path $MyPath
```

Returns 3.

Unfortunately, I had to wrap `Split-Path` in a `Try..Catch` because if you pass it the root path then it throws an error. This is unfortunate because it means genuine errors won't cause an exception to occur but can't see a way around this at the moment.

The advantage of working using `Split-Path` is that you should get a consistent count regardless of whether a trailing `\` is used or not.

Comment: I like this. Could you do a `Split-Path -Leaf` you think? Something like `If ($Parent -eq ("C:\" + $Leaf))` to perform the check on if it is at its last loop?

Comment: I was trying to avoid anything that meant hard coding in the root letter/path.

Comment: `($Path -split "\\")[0] + "\"` Could be added to dynamically get it. Not sure it would work if the path was a UNC path though.

Comment: Another option would potentially be to get the root via `(Get-Item $Path).Root.Name`. But then the function only works for real paths and could also be tripped by permission issues i guess.

Comment: It's all working smoothly. Used $file.PSpath inside foreach-loop, and at the start $path. The difference of the two -1  gave me the relative distance, which I needed. YOU ARE AWESOM!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to get the depth in the folder structure for all files in a location. Hope this helps get you in the right direction

```
New-Item -Path "C:\Logs\Once\Test.txt" -Force
New-Item -Path "C:\Logs\Twice\Folder_In_Twice\Test.txt" -Force

$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Logs\" -Recurse -Include *.* | Select-Object FullName

foreach ($File in $Files) {
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$Split_File = $File.FullName -split "\\"
    Write-Output ($File.FullName + " -- Depth is " + $Split_File.Count)
}
```

Output is this just for illustration

```
C:\Logs\Once\Test.txt -- Depth is 4
C:\Logs\Twice\Folder_In_Twice\Test.txt -- Depth is 5
```

Comment: Tried it out! The thing is, I've already figured out a similar way (at pretty much the same time you put out your answer) by counting the '\'-Seperators in $file.PSpath. But the result is the 'distance' to absolute root, not to $path either way. Need to find the offset before entering the for-loop then, I guess. Greatly appreciate your help